# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Message Receiver not found for AxisOperation: requestSecurityToken

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

We are trying to access SAML-secured service hosted on WSO2 ESB via unsecure proxy-service. We use WSO2 Identity Server as a STS engine, STS is secured using UserName token service.

While requesting STS service for Token we are getting the following exception:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Message Receiver not found for AxisOperation: requestSecurityToken
>
> [2015-06-20 15:16:05,846] ERROR -  Fault processing response message through Axis2 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker}
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Message Receiver not found for AxisOperation: requestSecurityToken
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Policy used for secured service and RequestTokenResponse from WSO2IS are listed below. MEXService which is mentioned in the policy is a proxy service used for returning WS-Policy for STS service.

Policy: http://pastebin.com/qgSqe01n

RequestTokenServiceResponse: http://pastebin.com/WXeMKFtm

Comment: What version of the identity server are you using?

Comment: it's 5.0.0. We've solved the problem by switching from call mediator to callout